# WIF Error: "ID3094: Cannot create WS-Federation message from the given URI 'http://myurl'"

Tags: wif, sts-securitytokenservice

Can anyone tell me what this error means?
I just starting getting it from the STS I build using WIF and I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is missing some required parameters.

A message instance is created from the information present in the URL using the [WSFederationMessage.CreateFromUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationmessage.createfromuri.aspx) method.

This fragment from the MSDN page should provide an idea of what's going on:

> Returns an appropriate implementation of WSFederationMessage based on the wa parameter in the query string; for example, if wa parameter is "wsignout1.0" then a SignOutRequestMessage object is returned.
>
> Other exceptions may be thrown depending on the combination and values of parameters present in the query string.
>
> Invokes the TryCreateFromUri method.